# "Cannot GET /" Error while running using node

Tags: node.js, localhost, ejs, nodemon

When I try to run my app.js using nodemon in hyper terminal it shows the error **cannot GET /**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");

const homeStartingContent = "Lacus vel facilisis"
const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea"
const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend"

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));


app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.render("home",{startingContent:homeStartingContent});
});

app.get("/about",function(req, res){
  res.render("about",{about:aboutContent});
});

app.get("/contact",function(req, res){
  res.render("contact", {contact:contactContent});
});

app.get("/compose", function(req, res){
  res.render("compose");
});

app.post("/compose", function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body.postTitle);
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

when I use VSCode terminal to run it will work fine. I have no idea whats wrong in this. Please, Help!!!

Comment: If you have `cannot GET /`  error, maybe you are launching the wrong app. In this code clearly we can see the `/` route. Try to console.log() something, before `render`